# How can PostScript find its full windows filename?

Tags: postscript

I'm looking for a workaround to PostScript's apparent inability to use relative windows filenames. Is there some PS command sequence to find the current windows diretory in use?

Comment: No. PostScript interpreters need not have a file system at all, the Apple LaserWriter for example did not. Where they do have a filesystem the exact details are dependent on the interpreter. There is no PostScript operator to return the CWD, you are expected to know the location of any files you want to open on the device (usually by using a %os% device specifier). Files you create are obviously relative to the CWD and so easily referenced. But the short answer is that there is no standard way to get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

As Ken comments, PostScript itself has no way to discover this information. If you need this information inside the PostScript program, then you'll need to pass it in somehow. With ghostscript, you could do something like `` gs -sCWD=`cwd` myprogram.ps ``. And then the program can access the string as `CWD` or `/CWD load`.